# Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync() taking too much time for returning its value in UWP with xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, geolocation, gps

Initially Allow Apps to access location and my app's access precise location is off in my windows machine. I opened my app and GPS is unavailable. I enabled both Allow Apps to access location and my app's access precise location. after that, I tap the location icon and it will trigger  Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync() to check GPS-enabled via dependency service. Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync() taking too much time for returning its value in UWP with Xamarin.Forms. Need to reduce the time or better alternatives with lesser timing in UWP for Xamarin.Forms.

```
 var accessStatus = await Geolocator.RequestAccessAsync();
```

Comment: what does "too much time" mean?  5s?  5 minutes?  Does your device have GPS capability, or is it falling back on IP geolocation?  Have you tried different precision levels to see if that has an impact?

Comment: Also make sure to run it on the main thread. That might be an issue on Windows as well I think

Comment: @Jason it is tested on Windows 10 machine and it has location service in location privacy settings. And it takes 1 minutes 30 seconds

Comment: Could you please tell me does this behavior happen on other devices?

Comment: I too see this issue in my Windows desktop app running on Dell Precision 7550 laptop. RequestAccessAsync() takes 1.5 minutes to return result.